# LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, warnings

I have a problem with my bibliography. Though my bib file is not empty, I get the message that it is. Also my .bbl file is empty.

This is my document:

```
  \documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{Thesis}

  \begin{document}

  \cite{Author2010}

  \bibliographystyle{unsrt} 
  \bibliography{testbib.bib} 

  \end{document}
```

And this is my bib file:

```
 @BOOK{Author2010,
          author = {Author, This},
           pages = {301},
       publisher = {Springer},
           title = {{Book}},
            year = {2010}
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing a comma at the end of the `author` line and BibTeX should have warned about the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, this was a small error in my minimal example, but not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is `\bibliography{testbib}` (*without* the `.bib` ending).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't provide any ~\cite{reference} command in the document file, then this warning will always occur despite having a full bibliography file.